# Jackson structured programming diagram (format a tree diagram)

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I'm trying to create a [Jackson structured programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_structured_programming) diagram. This is basically a simple tree diagram with the exception that boxes can either have a circle (O) or a star (*) in the upper right corner of each box. I am using the TikZ libary for the diagram but I don't know how to extend the styles to achieve this. Here is the unfinished diagram:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=red!50!black!50, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow, minimum width=5em, minimum height=3em, level distance=10cm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    circle/.style={rectangle, draw=red!50!black!50, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow, minimum width=5em, minimum height=3em, level distance=10cm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    %SHOULD CONTAIN THE CIRCLES
    star/.style={rectangle, draw=red!50!black!50, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue, drop shadow, minimum width=5em, minimum height=3em, level distance=10cm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
     %SHOULD CONTAIN THE STARS       
]
\node (State00) [box] {Jackson Diagramm}
 [sibling distance=3cm]
    child {node (a) [box] {int a = 1}}
    child {node (a) [box] {boolean n = true}}
    child {node (a) [box] {boolean z = true}}
    child {[sibling distance=4cm] node (d) [circle] {if (n)}
        child{  [sibling distance=3cm] node (e) [star] {while (z)}
        child {node (f) [box] {n = !z}}
        child {node (g) [box] {a++}}
        child { [sibling distance=4cm] node (h) [circle] {a <= 10}
                child {node (i) [box] {z = true}}
                child {node (j) [box] {System.out.println( "z\(>\)10")}}
            }
        }
        child {node (k) [box] {System.out.println(a)}} 
        child {node (l) [box] {System.out.println(z)}}      
    } 
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Current output:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `label={[xshift=-1.25em, yshift=-2.25ex]north east:$\ast$}` to place additional graphics within the node:

[image]

### Notes:

- I changed the colors to make it easier to see where the special nodes are.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={rectangle, draw=red!50!black!50, rounded corners=1mm, fill=blue!25, drop shadow, minimum width=5em, minimum height=3em, level distance=10cm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    circle/.style={rectangle, draw=red!50!black!50, rounded corners=1mm, fill=green!25, drop shadow, minimum width=5em, minimum height=3em, level distance=10cm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black, label={[xshift=-1.25em, yshift=-2.25ex]north east:$\circ$}},
    %SHOULD CONTAIN THE CIRCLES
    star/.style={rectangle, draw=red!50!black!50, rounded corners=1mm, fill=red!25, drop shadow, minimum width=5em, minimum height=3em, level distance=10cm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black, label={[xshift=-1.25em, yshift=-2.25ex]north east:$\ast$}},
     %SHOULD CONTAIN THE STARS       
]
\node (State00) [box] {Jackson Diagramm}
 [sibling distance=3cm]
    child {node (a) [box] {int a = 1}}
    child {node (a) [box] {boolean n = true}}
    child {node (a) [box] {boolean z = true}}
    child {[sibling distance=4cm] node (d) [circle] {if (n)}
        child{  [sibling distance=3cm] node (e) [star] {while (z)}
        child {node (f) [box] {n = !z}}
        child {node (g) [box] {a++}}
        child { [sibling distance=4cm] node (h) [circle] {a <= 10}
                child {node (i) [box] {z = true}}
                child {node (j) [box] {System.out.println( "z\(>\)10")}}
            }
        }
        child {node (k) [box] {System.out.println(a)}} 
        child {node (l) [box] {System.out.println(z)}}      
    } 
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess with this (probably only simple) method the symbols are positioned relative to the center instead of the corner. So if the condition is longer, the symbol appears rather in the middle than in the corner, correct?

Comment: @Patrick: No that is not correct. They are placed relative to the `north east` of the node so should be in the desired location.  Try it and let me know if that does not work.

Comment: Ah yes! I set `xshift` to `-1em` and it works absolutely perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a different approach, namely the `path picture` key and the `path picture bounding box` pseudo-node.

I cleaned up the style definitions and renamed especially the `circle` style, because there is already a shape `circle` which could lead to confusion.

I’ve put the the circle of directly in the rounded corner (you can of course adjust the shifting to move it further to the node’s center).

The `starred` style accepts one optional argment (default: `5`) which denotes the number of corners. The radius for the outer corners is `1mm`, for the inner corners it is `.5mm`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    draw=red!50!black!50,
    rounded corners=1mm,
    fill=blue,
    drop shadow,
    minimum width=5em,
    minimum height=3em,
    level distance=10cm,
    text centered,
    anchor=north,
    text=white
    },
  circled/.style={
    box,
    path picture={
      \path[draw=red!50!black!50, fill=blue!50] ([shift={(-1mm,-1mm)}]path picture bounding box.north east) circle[radius = 1mm];
    }
  },
  starred/.style={
    box,
    path picture={
       \path[sharp corners,draw=red!50!black!50, fill=blue!50,] ([shift={(-1.5mm,-1.5mm)}]path picture bounding box.north east) + (1/#1*360+90:1mm) \foreach \i in {1,...,#1} {-- + (\i/#1*360+90:1mm) -- + (\i.5/#1*360+90:.5mm)} -- cycle;
    }
  },
  starred/.default=5,% default number of corners
]
\node (State00) [box] {Jackson Diagramm}
 [sibling distance=3cm]
    child {node (a) [box] {int a = 1}}
    child {node (a) [box] {boolean n = true}}
    child {node (a) [box] {boolean z = true}}
    child {[sibling distance=4cm] node (d) [circled] {if (n)}
        child{  [sibling distance=3cm] node (e) [starred] {while (z)}
        child {node (f) [box] {n = !z}}
        child {node (g) [box] {a++}}
        child { [sibling distance=4cm] node (h) [circled] {a <= 10}
                child {node (i) [box] {z = true}}
                child {node (j) [box] {System.out.println( "z\(>\)10")}}
            }
        }
        child {node (k) [box] {System.out.println(a)}} 
        child {node (l) [box] {System.out.println(z)}}      
    } 
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice, I like how customizable this is (though more complex). Stars look great :)